# Writing line numbers on an input text File

Tags: java

I need to write a program that will produce a new file  where each line of text has a line number, given an input file with no line numbers. For example:

Given line:
"sixteen"

Output line:
" 1 | sixteen",

Line    numbers are formatted   right-aligned   in  3   spaces, followed by a   |   character (with one space   before
and after), and followed    by  the text    in  that    line.

```
public class LineNumbers {
public static void process(File input, File output) {
    Scanner scanner;
    PrintWriter writer;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(input);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        writer = new PrintWriter(output);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 1; scanner.hasNextLine(); i++) {
        String s1 = scanner.nextLine();
        String s2 = "   " + i + " | " + s1;
        writer.print(s2);
    }
    scanner.close();
    writer.close();
}
}
```

This is the code I have, where the string s2 == the output I need, but how do I transition this into an output file?

*****EDIT*****

This is one of the tests that needs to be run, where only one line is input in the file. However, in the tester, it only has two spaces in front of the line number, and when I change my code to match, the test passes. All the other testers are written similarly and I think that may be causing the issue

```
    @Test
public void testOneLine() {
    try {
        // create file
        File        input  = folder.newFile( "input.txt" );
        File        output = folder.newFile( "output.txt" );

        PrintWriter write  = new PrintWriter( input );
        write.println( "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit." );
        write.close();

        // invoke program
        LineNumbers.process( input, output );

        // verify file results
        assertTrue  ( "Output file does not exist", output.exists() );
        Scanner scan     = new Scanner( output );
        String[] result = new String[] { 
                "  1 | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
        };
        for (String expected : result) {
            if (scan.hasNext()) {
                String actual = scan.nextLine();
                assertEquals( "Incorrect result", expected, actual );
            }
            else {
                fail( String.format( "Unexpected end of file: expected \"%s\"", expected ));
                break;
            }
        }
        assertFalse ( "File contains more data than expected", scan.hasNext() );
        scan.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        fail( "No exception should be thrown" );
    }
}
```

Comment: You already doing it. What is the problem ?

Comment: It would help if you would tell what's the issue, @Alex

Comment: It's failing my JUnit test, I don't know why though. I think the test could be written incorrectly though, looking closer at it. Is there a way to use printf() to write the output file?

Comment: Can you post the test and failure?

Comment: You want me to post the entire test file? It's over 400 lines long

Comment: @AlexS So make a shorter test file.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many spaces preceding your line number. When you are told to provide the line number *in* three spaces, it should be formatted as in one of these examples:

__1

_22

333

So that there are three characters total, including any spaces.